# Create multiple DIVS on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create multiple DIVs when onClick() is triggered.

I've used an increment value to create multiple DIVs. But this doesn't fully work. See comments in code. (works perfect when a single DIV is used)

```
var tDV = 0;
$("#aTx").click(function() {
    var diagonalScl;
    var txSiz;
    tDV++;
    $("#ltn").append('<div id="aTextDV"+tDV class="ui-widget-content"></div>'); //WORKS
    $("#aTextDV"+tDV).append('<div class="txmoPos" id="mvTx" onclick="mTxt(this.id)"><img src="img/markers/img3.png"/></div>'); // DOSEN'T WORK (no image, onClick does not work)
    $("#aTextDV"+tDV).append('<div class="txdlPos" id="dleTx" onclick="dTxt(this.id)"><img src="img/markers/img1.png"/></div>');// DOSEN'T WORK (no image, onClick does not work)
    $("#aTextDV"+tDV).append('<div class="txrsPos" id="rzTx" onclick="rTxt(this.id)"><img src="img/markers/img2.png"/></div>');// DOSEN'T WORK (no image, onClick does not work)
    $("#aTextDV"+tDV).append('<textarea rows="3" id="aText">Type Here</textarea>');
    alert("#aTextDV"+tDV)// DOSEN'T WORK (no textarea)
```

Comment: Can you post your complete function?  It doesn't seem to be closed (missing `})`) so I can't tell if it's the end of the function or not.

Comment: This looks like if you do multiple clicks you'll end up with multiple elements which have the same _id_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating your DOM element, you are not concatenating the string.

This line :

```
'<div id="aTextDV"+tDV class="ui-widget-content"></div>'
```

Should be :

```
'<div id="aTextDV'+tDV+'" class="ui-widget-content"></div>'
```

Bonus tip, you can chaine Query method for better performance :

```
$("#aTextDV"+tDV)
.append('<div class="txmoPos" id="mvTx" onclick="mTxt(this.id)"><img src="img/markers/img3.png"/></div>'); 
.append('<div class="txdlPos" id="dleTx" onclick="dTxt(this.id)"><img src="img/markers/img1.png"/></div>');
.append('<div class="txrsPos" id="rzTx" onclick="rTxt(this.id)"><img src="img/markers/img2.png"/></div>');
.append('<textarea rows="3" id="aText">Type Here</textarea>');
```

Comment: HOw can I put the parent DIV inside the onClick function? `onclick="mTxt(aTextDV+tDV)">`

Comment: @JonaNathali My advice would be to know use inline click handler, but to answer your question, it would be `onclick="this"`.

Comment: `"this"` did not equal to `"aTextDV"+tDV`

Comment: @JonaNathali oh, i though you wanted the element! If you want a string, you do : `onclick="mTxt(\'aTextDV'+tDV+'\')"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ltn").append('<div id="aTextDV"+tDV class="ui-widget-content"></div>');
```

is the line with the bug.  It should be:

```
$("#ltn").append('<div id="aTextDV"'+tDV + 'class="ui-widget-content"></div>');
```